# Phonegap - Reverse ajax

Tags: cordova, reverse-ajax

Trying to make a PhoneGap application. According to scenario there slave phones and one or two master phone, slave ones start to send some data to a server and server processes data and sends some new data to master ones.

Thinking to send data with json but dont have any idea how to deliver from server to master ones. Is it possible with phoneGap? Can i use "Reverse ajax"? or any idea?

There are lots of groups with one or two master and dozen of slaves. Project is for both Android and ios.

Comment: reverse ajax is something similar to what happens in push notifications. and its possible

Comment: hope this helps.. http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

[Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html) for Android is the solution for push notification. It was called C2DM previously.